# ¿Cómo alinear mi formulario en JSF en filas?

Tags: html, css

Tengo los siguientes campos en un formulario y quiero que estén acomodados como en la imagen, pero no logro alinearlos ni poner los textos en esa forma, ademas quiero agregar otros campos debajo y que igual estén alineados de esa manera, como le puedo hacer con css? no estoy usando bootstrap

```html
<f:view>
    <h:form id="form_pruebas" class="form-horizontal">
        <p:panel>

             

             <div class="container">

             <div class="form-group">

                <h:outputLabel for="intentosAp" value="Intentos de aplicación" style="display: inline-block width: 70px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <h:inputText id="intentosAp" value="" style="width: 60px;" required="true" maxlength="2"/>

     

                <h:outputLabel for="intentosExi" value="Intentos exitosos:" style="display: inline-block width: 25px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <h:inputText id="intentosExi" value="" style="width: 60px;" required="true" maxlength="3"/>

     

                <h:outputLabel for="intentosFall" value="Intentos fallidos" style="display: inline-block width: 50px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <h:inputText id="intentosFall" style="width: 60px;" value="" required="true" maxlength="3"/>

            </div>
            </div>
        </p:panel>

    </h:form>
</f:view>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: esa solo es una imagen de como quiero que se vean mis inputs, es como un boceto, pero así como esta mi codigo se ve horizontal pero amontonado, y los labels no se ven asi como quiero

Comment: 3 campos, y abajo metere igual otros tres, pero no se como acomodar los labels para que se vean asi y no todo el texto seguido

Answer (score 1):

No se si será la mejor opción pero propongo

Dado que no uso JSF me limité a recrear un ejemplo con HTML para
describir como pudieras resolverlo:

- Envolvemos en un div interno en el form a todos los elementos que serían
  tanto las labels como los inputs
- A este div por medio de su clase, le damos un display flex, para que sus
  elementos sean flexibles
- Necesitamos resetear el ancho de los inputs, entonces los recuperamos por
  medio de su clase
- Para separar a la derecha a cada uno de los inputs de su vecino label le damos
  un margin de 30px
- Aplicamos los mismos pasos para el segundo grupo de 3 elementos
- Solo varía por que mediante la pseudoclase nth-child eligo al div del segundo
  grupo y le doy un margin superior para separarlos

Propuesta:

```html
    <style>
      .formulario {
        border: 1px solid;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 600px;
      }
      .formulario-container {
        display: flex;
      }
      .formulario-container__caja {
        margin: 0 30px 0 5px;
        width: 50px;
      }
      .formulario-container:nth-child(2) {
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <form class="formulario" action="">
          <div class="formulario-container">
            <label for="intentos">Intentos de Aplicación</label>
            <input class="formulario-container__caja" type="text">
            <label for="intentos">Intentos de Aplicación</label>
            <input class="formulario-container__caja" type="text">
            <label for="intentos">Intentos de Aplicación</label>
            <input class="formulario-container__caja" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="formulario-container">
            <label class="etiqueta-aviso" for="intentos">Intentos de Aplicación</label>
            <input class="formulario-container__caja" type="text">
            <label class="etiqueta-aviso" for="intentos">Intentos de Aplicación</label>
            <input class="formulario-container__caja" type="text">
            <label class="etiqueta-aviso" for="intentos">Intentos de Aplicación</label>
            <input class="formulario-container__caja" type="text">
          </div>
    </form>
```